# A more concise way of assigning instance variables from initialize?

Tags: ruby

I have a few classes I'm using to contain data (and a few methods on it) in Ruby. For instance:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(bar, biz, baz)
    @bar=bar
    @biz=biz
    @baz=baz
  end
end
```

Is there a less repetitive way of propagating these initialization arguments into instance variables?

Comment: If it's just a dumb class, considre using a `Struct`

Comment: And you can `class C < Struct.new(...)` if you want to add methods.

Answer (score 2):

One liner, but I find this can obscure things:

```
@bar,@biz,@baz = bar,biz,baz
```

Comment: I was really hoping to have some way of not duplicating the names 2 times to assign it to instance variables

Comment: You aren't duplicating the names, at all.  "Joe" and "Joen" are not the same name, so why do you think `@bar` and `bar` are the same names?  The duplication, in my opinion, doesn't count from the argument list and actually using those arguments in the body of the method.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo
  def initialize(*args)
    raise ArgumentError unless args.length == 3
    @bar, @biz, @baz = args
  end
end
```

Comment: but then calling Foo.new with more or less args would fail to produce an error wouldn't it?

Comment: It would have, until the edit.  Except that the additional line is more typing and more to remember than just assigning your variables the way you have initially done.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way is to use a [Struct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Struct.html):

```
class Foo < Struct.new(:bar, :biz, :baz)
  # custom methods go here
end
```

Struct.new will return a class with the initializer and accessors set up for you (other than that, it's just a normal class). If you don't need any custom methods, you can also define a struct inline (e.g. `Foo = Struct.new(:bar, :biz, :baz)`).